# Partial tag visibility in Recently Viewed tab

Tags: bug, ios-app, recent-activity

Tags partially visible in Recently Viewed tab in normal mode:

> [image: normal]

and edit mode (compare with normal mode picture):

> [image: edit]

- App Version: 1.7.0
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)